# php difference between pack() and unpack()

Tags: php, pack, unpack

in php 4.4.4 having:

```
$hbc=pack("LL",82603088,82602992);
list($v1,$v2)=unpack("L2",$hbc);
echo("v1=".$v1." v2=".$v2);
```

result is:

> v1= v2=82603088

I already have some hours wrapping my head aroud this...
thanks

Comment: if I do `$ar=unpack("C*",$hbc);echo(implode(", ",$ar));`, I get _80, 108, 236, 4, 240, 107, 236, 4_, that's ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not withing the pack or unpack, but inside the `list()`.

Turn on notices! Your code will complain like this:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ...
```

That should make you wonder. If you dump the array that is returned by unpack, it is correct:

```
array(2) {
  [1] =>
  int(82603088)
  [2] =>
  int(82602992)
}
```

And then there is this tiny little note on the docs page of `list()`:

> list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

Your array does not start at index 0, and the notice likes to tell you that.

The quick fix is:

```
list(,$v1,$v2)=unpack("L2",$hbc); // add a comma to skip index 0
```

A better approach might be to use `unpack` to create named array indices:

```
$unpacked = unpack("L2v/",$hbc);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  'v1' =>
  int(82603088)
  'v2' =>
  int(82602992)
}
```

Comment: I must admit that I haven't paid the required attention to the examples of unpack, but from _Returns an associative array containing unpacked elements of binary string_ it could as well been 0-based. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the php.net [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php#45188).

```
$int_list = array_merge(unpack("s*", $some_binary_data));
```

This will essentially reset your index keys starting at 0.